Changing the active version of Python on a Mac
I run a set of python scripts developed for an organization I work with to perform various text manipulations. I have limited commandline/UNIX-style experience.
I installed Python on my Mac laptop several years ago and had no reason to make any changes thereafter. Recently I purchased a new MacBook Pro with a silicon M4 chip. I used the Apple Migration Assistant app to transfer my files to the new laptop.
Not unexpectedly when I tried to run python on the new laptop I got the following:
$ python
/usr/local/opt/pyenv/libexec/pyenv-exec: line 48: /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python: Bad CPU type in executable

I then installed a new version of python using the python-3.13.0-macos11.pkg downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/
When I tried to run python again, I received the same error as before.
In subsequent searching on the Internet I found https://mac.install.guide/ among other sites recommending wholly different techniques for installing python.
I have determined that .zprofile contains
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

/usr/local/opt/pyenv/libexec/pyenv-exec appears to be a script for selecting a particular version of python, but .pyenv/versions contains only the folder 3.10.0, with no reference to 3.13.0.
How can I make version 3.13 active and the default? Can I remove version 3.10, as it is clearly incompatible with the hardware?

@matt Quite the contrary, it looks like the pyenv shims from the old laptop were copied over, but they reference x86 binaries presumably used by an older Intel-based laptop, rather than the ARM binaries the new laptop requires.

Success! Many thanks. The responses gave me enough hints to get the job done. What I did was:

reinstalled Xcode Command Line Tools
uninstalled old Homebrew
installed new Homebrew (different default location)
used Homebrew to reinstall git
added brew and git folders to the path
used Homebrew to install pyenv
reinstalled python with pyenv
used pyenv to set new version as the default
used pyenv to delete the old version


@hross you should make that an answer. and accept it.

Sorry but I don't know what you mean and what I should do.

Scroll down and at the bottom of the page you should be able to create an answer. Then after you do that there will be a up/down vote arrows and below that a check. You can click the check and it "accepts" your answer.

The responses gave me enough hints to get the job done. What I did was: -

reinstalled Xcode Command Line Tools
uninstalled old Homebrew
installed new Homebrew (different default location)
used Homebrew to reinstall git
added brew and git folders to the path
used Homebrew to install pyenv
reinstalled python with pyenv
used pyenv to set new version as the default
used pyenv to delete the old version

